# How to set a gdb watchpoint to a value stored in register?

Tags: debugging, gdb, breakpoints, watchpoint

I'm trying to detect stack overflow in some function, and want to set a watchpoint to a memory pointed by the RSP register. I can't just set a watchpoint to a certain address as the function could be called from a different places. So I want to set breakpoints at the start and the end of the function, and force them to enable/disable the watchpoint.

But neither way of setting a watchpoint works for me. E.g. `wa $rsp` watches the register; the

```
set $myvar = $rsp
wa $myvar
```

makes watchpoint to trace... changes of the $myvar! Not the value it stores!

Weird, I'm sure, here is should be a way, but I don't know one...

UPD: looks I found a bug in gdb. Two:

```
(gdb) wa *$rsp
Attempt to dereference a generic pointer.
(gdb) set $myvar = $rsp
(gdb) wa *$myvar
Attempt to dereference a generic pointer.
```

UPD: don't know why, but the `wa &*$myvar` sets a breakpoint to the $myvar, though shouldn't. Bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GDB doesn't let you explicitly dereference `void *` pointers such as `$rsp`. It doesn't know the size or the format of the pointed-to value.

Do `watch *(char *)$rsp` or `watch *(int *)$rsp`, etc., instead to watch for a change in what the register points to.  (Either by memory writes, or by the register changing to point somewhere else.)

Using `watch -l *(int*)$rsp` will watch for changes to that 4-byte memory location, even if `$rsp` later changes.  (Snapshotting the address).

On x86 CPUs, `watch -l` can use a hardware watchpoint, unlike without `-l` where it's monitoring for a change in evaluating the whole expression.